# zoomScale() doesn't work in QGIS 2.14 standalone c++ application

Tags: qgis, scale, c++, zoom

Can't set scale for my canvas with `mapCanvas.zoomScale(50000);` Seems like canvas is zooming to 1:1 and for a few seconds I can't zoom in or zoom out with mouse wheel. Any suggestions?